# How to transform Google/OpenStreetMap Co-ordinates to ESPG:3857 Co-ordinates?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-maps, web-mercator

I have an old map successfully layered on OpenStreetMap on QGIS and have been able to add delineated text points from a CSV file using WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator ESPG:3857 co-ordinates.

I have tried http://epsg.io/ set on the co-ordinate system but it isn't very easy to search for particular small road locations.

As such, I would like to use an online search tool such as Google maps or OpenStreetMaps to identify particular locations. Is there any easy way to convert these to the ESPG:3857 co-ordinate system for use in CVS files and QGIS?

For example, London's Victoria Station in ESPG:3857 is roughly -16321.992778, 6709299.869156 . On google maps, it is roughly: 51.4952074,-0.1463113 .

(From a very new user)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the most fool proof way to convert between CRS in QGIS is by creating a new file.

If the layer is in the layer list, right click and choose the export option. Choose to "Save Features As" (if that is what you want).

When the export window opens, you'll see a drop down for a variety of file formats (I default to geopackage unless I have a specific reason to do otherwise, which I frequently do).

Set the file path and name and the layer name if need be.

The fourth drop down sets the target CRS of the new file. Find the CRS you need and export, choosing a subset of columns if necessary.

[image: QGIS export menu]